# "The memory could not be written" error in virtualbox on Windows 10

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, virtualbox, ram

so I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VirtualBox and I have windows 10 1903 running as host, and this error started happening since I installed the VM, I'll be working normally and all things going well, then this error shows up:

[image]

I zipped the log file in a [zip file](https://gofile.io/?c=Kr6tS1) if you click the link it will download it automatically,

Specs of the machine:

- Acer Predator Helios 300 2018.
- i7 8750H
- GTX 1060
- 16GB DDR4 2666MHz
- 256 NVMe SSD

It is running the latest version of virtualbox and the latest extension pack. I assigned 3 cores and the execution cap to 100%, and it has 8GB of virtual memory, 128MB video memory, and 3D acceleration enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Can you disable the 3D Accelaration in virtual box for this VM and then reboot the VM. I had the same issue after disabling 3D Acceleration it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running MacOS on a Windows 10 (Host). I just changed the graphics controller option in Settings → *Display* to *VBoxSVGA*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after coming back from the holidays, with my last log-in nearly two weeks earlier. My solution in Virtual Box was to go to:

File > Quit (or Ctrl + Q)

A warning message appeared to say that a shutdown will commence and may affect any unsaved data from applications still open. (In my case, I only had the command line open so that was fine so I selected OK).

I then selected my virtual instance in Virtual Box and selected Start again, and I could regain access.

Through this process Virtual Box restarted my VM, rebooting with my account and login. Note, any previously opened applications will now be closed, so any unsaved data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

For me i have discarded the session and reopened again . Its working now

Comment: This was already said in the 3 rd comment. You are just repeating what has already been said.

Comment: He quit the VM he said. I said i discard the session and opened again. There is a difference.